# Anyone know how i create a class wherin my second property is determined by my first property declared in constructor

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can tell on the picture i want to create two properties in constructor. One is chromosome and the other fitness_val. chromosome will be an array and in fitnessValue i need to acces this array. I cant seem to find a solution.

I am not sure what i should do. Do you guys see any solution?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Pass the array to the function as an argument...?

Comment: silly me, thanks anyway - i'm new to coding

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you should fix your typo at line 4, you've written **chromsome** instead of **chromosome**. Javascript thinks you're looking for a property named chromsome, and it's undefined since due to typo it doesn't exist.